# Failed to read data form the fetched resource in React. (Cannot read property 'backdrop_path' of undefined)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have fetched some data from the endpoint and stored it in the state. When I try to view the result in the console it works fine. But when I try to consume it in the component then it throws an error telling that the key is undefined. Here is my code and the **heroImage** is undefined, Help, please

```
const Home = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ movies: [] });
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  const fetchMovies = async endpoint => {
    setIsError(false);
    setIsLoading(false);

    const params = new URLSearchParams(endpoint);
    if (!params.get("page")) {
      setState(prev => ({
        ...prev,
        movies: [],
        searchItem: params.get("query")
      }));
    }

    try {
      const result = await fetch(endpoint)).json();

      setState(prev => ({
        ...prev,
        movies: [...prev.movies, result.results],
        heroImage: prev.heroImage || result.results[0],
        currentPage: result.page,
        totalPage: result.total_pages
      }));
    } catch (error) {
      setIsError(true);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies(`${API_URL}movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&page=1`);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="rmdb-home">
        <div>
          <HeroImage
            image={`${IMAGE_BASE_URL}${BACKDROP_SIZE}${state.heroImage.backdrop_path}`}
          />
          <SearchBar />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Could you put this online so that we can debug it easily? Maybe Codesandbox? Also, don't use state and setState for your useState variables. Maybe try more specific like [movies, setMovies]

Answer (score 0):

because your component trying to access `heroImage` when first render, but it's undefined

So you need a initial state for `heroImage`
like

```js
const [state,setState]=useState({movies:[], heroImage: {}})
```

Comment: I think it's also a good idea to add an explanation why that initial state is necessary here.

Comment: @Nahid Islam of course init state is not mandatory, but ```state.heroImage.backdrop_path``` in render function access ```undefined.backdrop_path``` when first render, this will throw exeption